# PHP run javascript to collapse bootstrap div (no onClick)

Tags: javascript

I have a contactform hidden. When I hit the 'call' button the form will appear and you can fill in the form. After submitting successful the form is hidden, but when you forgot a field an error will appear and the form is hidden again. I want to show the form when an error appears by running a javascript to collapse (appear) the form again.

How do I do this without making the user click on a button to collapse the form?

The button:

```
<a href="#Foo" class="btn btn-download-cv btn-md full-width" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call </a>
```

The form in divs:

```
<div id="Foo" name="Foo" class="collapse">
form..
</div>
```

The message that will appear when you make a mistake:

```
$email_invalid   = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Incorrect e-mail adres.</div>";
```

I want to call the function when $email_invalid is being displayed and collapse the #Foo div.

Comment: if you submit the form via ajax instead of a full postback it will be much easier to handle this sort of thing

Comment: Just add the js code that shows the form in the php block that gets triggered when there is a validation error

Comment: Problem is the form is currently hidden / shown via PHP, not Javascript. I need to hit a javascript as it's hidden standard and want to show it only if an error appears.

Comment: Always send the html for the form with php, but have is `display:none`. If you put it inline you can easily change it with php to `display:block`; Now if you want to use javascript you can use that to change the display property too